# Difference between **timid** and **coward**

Tags: meaning, word-choice

While I was reading one-word substitutions in R.S. Agarwal's *General English* book, I came across the following question:

> **One who always runs away from danger**
>
> > a) escapist
> > b) timid
> > c) coward
> > d) shirker

They have given **b** as the correct answer. I reckoned that **timid** and **coward** both are the same. Can you please tell me the difference between *timid* and *coward*?

Comment: _Timid_ is not as strong as _coward,_ plus it's not even usually a noun, so I'm surprised it's listed as the correct answer.

Comment: I always felt that coward was a little more degrading. I think coward can be an insult whereas timid can't.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the thing is, *timid* means lack of courage and frightening easily. Not specifically like avoiding danger.
While a *coward* is someone who always runs away from danger, and is excessively afraid of danger.

The common thing is lack of courage and the difference is like not having a backbone or having a weak backbone.

You could say the degree of afraidness is more in a coward. And since the question contains the word "always", we can go for 'coward' as the answer.

I think your book is showing the wrong answer.

Comment: The distinction is so subtle, but I agree with you. Timid is an adjective, coward is a noun.  A noun it is a better fit to a question that asks for *one who*.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is given by David M in a comment.

You are asked for

> One who always runs away from danger
>
> a) escapist
>   b) timid 
>   c) coward 
>   d) shirker

The clue is 'one'—in other words a *person*. Therefore you are being asked for a noun.

'timid' is an adjective and so does not fulfill the requirements

'coward' is a noun and therefore a suitable candidate.

Unless you have failed to give us some of the context then, as someone else mentioned, your book is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I believe a coward  has a higher fear level than a timid. A coward does not try to get out of the fear even with support. Cowards would come up with ways to keep them hidden in their bubbles and would deny and reject mutual or dual support. Timids on the other hand have the potential to not be afraid yet they need some kind of support to get out of their bubble or fear..